# Predecir valores utilizando forecast.Arima y xreg

Tags: r

Estoy intentando predecir valores usando `forecast.Arima` y los argumentos `xtreg` y `h`

Mis códigos en R son:

```
monthlylFatal <- ts(Spainmonthly$fatalities, start=c(1995,1), end=          c(2013,12), frequency=12)
Spainpps <- ts(Spainmonthly$pps.2007, start=c(1995,1), end=c(2013,12), frequency=12)
Spainfinanc.cris <- ts(Spainmonthly$financ.cris.2008, start=c(1995,1), end=c(2013,12), frequency=12)
xreg <- cbind(Spainpps,Spainfinanc.cris)

arima1=Arima(logmonthlylFatal,order=c(0,1,1), seasonal=c(1,1,2), xreg = xreg)
forecast.arima1=forecast.Arima(arima1, xreg = xreg, h=84)
forecast.arima1
```

Me gustaría predecir valores desde Enero 2014 hasta Diciembre 2020 (h=84), pero como resultado obtengo predicciones hasta más del 2030. Por qué?